# How do I override the Header for field naming?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc, adodb

[Using SQL to query an Excel worksheet without a header row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511096) echos the information I have found in all my research. But that isn't what I am getting. Has there been a change in Excel 2016, or is my implementation wrong?

```
    Sub vndrrst()
        Dim cn As Object
        Set cn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
        strfilename = ThisWorkbook.Path
        cn.ConnectionString = _
                "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strfilename & _
                ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;imex=1"";"
        cn.Open
        Set rs = cn.Execute("select * from My_Text_File.txt where F2='04-62425'")
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set cn = Nothing
    End Sub
```

The error message reads "No value given for one or more required parameters." at the `Set rs` statement. When I change `F2` to `MFGID` (the actual field name given in the header of this text file), it both runs and gives accurate output in the debug window... even though `HDR=No`.

So, how can I use the F field names if the file has a header this time? The reason this becomes interesting is because I have many text/csv/delimited files sent to my FTP, some have headers, some don't, and some have headers sometimes.

Edit: the schema.ini file reads

```
[My_Text_File.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
```

in case it matters.

A different related question is [ADO Recordset to Excel spreadsheet opens properly in Excel 2007, has a missing parameter in Excel 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345000), but the motivation/project of the OP is different, and therefore the answer is irrelevant.

Comment: The article you quote is about querying an excel workbook without headers, not about querying a text file without headers. Have you tried loading the text file into excel and then querying it?

Comment: What format is the text file? Consider reading My_Text_File.txt and parsing out the first line?

Comment: @Paul True, it is about an excel workbook. Perhaps there may be an even closer match, but the principles of `HDR=No` are well explained there, which is the relevant point. Furthermore, 'a text file without headers' isn't the problem here. And 'loading the text file into excel and then querying it' is not what I am looking for. As I said in the question, I can and do easily change my query string to get the information. I want to 'override the header' information, not figure out how to query a text file.

Comment: @Alex The `Format=TabDelimited` found in the schema.ini file tells the connection string that the format of the file is tab delimited. And this may be the relevant information here, as I have been able to replicate this problem with another flat file, tab delimited, of a different source, size, and extension. On the other hand, the sources I have found seem to make no distinction for purposes of the `HDR` property.

Comment: @Paul Ok, maybe not 'well explained'. There was another with an answer by Fionnuala that I thought I was linking. I apologize, when you are your own boss, you don't sleep well. Anyway, a different question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31345000/) has the same topic, but different reason for asking, so I can't use that answer.